# Raspbery Pi Pico not connecting to the PC /Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I am new to Raspberry in general so I dont have a lot of experience with these devices.

I recently bought the raspberry pi pico and downloaded the micropython file from raspberry´s website. Everyting was going great but when I turned my raspberry off, the next day the Pico was not being recognized by the Thonny IDE (in the previous day Thonny was recognizing and working great.)

I tried connecting to the PC and download again the files. And it worked! But when I tried to connect to the raspberry again there was no sign off life.

I tried connecting again and again but there is no sign of life. I even tried pressing the Bootsell button while connecting but nothing happened.

If u can help me I would be very gratefull. And if you need more info just ask and I will tell u what happened in more detail.

Thanks for the attention,
André

Comment: You'll probably get a better response on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com since that is dedicated to the hardware whereas this site is about programming.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot :)